# Azure analytics query row count

Tags: azure-log-analytics

I would like to count the number of rows in my query. Is this possible in azure analytics query language? And how should I do this?

```
requests
| where name == "MyName"
| summarize by tostring(customDimensions.myCustomProperty)
```

Result:
    customDimensions_myCustomProperty
    item1
    item2
    item3
    item4

In SQL I would just do this:

```
select count(distinct(customDimensions.myCustomProperty)
from requests
where name == "MyName"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
requests
| where name == "MyName"
| summarize by tostring(customDimensions.myCustomProperty)
| summarize count()
```